# Symfony2 can't include custom class

Tags: class, symfony, doctrine

Class 'AdoDoctrineModel' not found in C:\wamp\www\test\src\Ado\FrontendBundle\Helper\AdoFactory.php on line 22

```
<?php

namespace Ado\FrontendBundle\Helper;

use AdoDoctrineModel;
use AdoApiModel;

class AdoFactory {
    protected $adapter; 

    public function __construct($container) {
        $this->adapter = $container->getParameter('adapter'); 
    }

    public function getModel()  {

        switch($this->adapter)
        {
            case 'API':
            case 'Doctrine': 
                $class = 'Ado' . $this->adapter. 'Model'; 
                return new $class;
            break;
            default: throw new Exception("unsupported format: " . $type);
        }
    }
}

?>
```

And AdoDoctrineModel.php

```
namespace Ado\FrontendBundle\Helper;

class AdoDoctrineModel {

    public function __construct() {

    }

}
```

I have tried changing use path in AdoFactory to full path, also adding "use {...} as AdoDoctrineModel"
Tried \new AdoDoctrineModel

Any help would be great!

Comment: Have you tried `use Ado\FrontendBundle\Helper\AdoDoctrineModel;`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove that code :

```
use AdoDoctrineModel;
use AdoApiModel;
```

and everything should work fine. you need to refresh your understanding of how php namespaces work, check the doc on namespaces.

what you are currently telling your app is fetch a non existent \AdoDoctrineModel class and \AdoApiModel instead of of `\Ado\FrontendBundle\Helper\AdoDoctrineModel` and `\Ado\FrontendBundle\Helper\AdoApiModel` classes.

Answer (score 1):

I assume your are using Composer (Symfony 2.1.x). Your code seems fine to me, I would check `composer.json` file for this section:

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-0": {
        "": "src/"
    }
}
```

And then issue:

```
composer dump-autoload
```

Of course file `AdoDoctrineModel.php` should be placed inside `src/Ado/FrontendBundle/Helper` folder. There is no need for `use` statement as both classes are in the same namespace.